# How to protect branch with "Require pull request reviews before merging"

Tags: git, github

I have posted this on github.community but it hasn't drawn any solutions.

I am trying to protect the master branch from single person direct push: every change must be made through a (feature) branch followed by pull request to be approved by another (or a specific) developer. In the repo's settings this feature seems to be able to do this:

**Require pull request reviews before merging**

*When enabled, all commits must be made to a non-protected branch and submitted via a pull request with the required number of approving reviews and no changes requested before it can be merged into a branch that matches this rule.*

I have turned this on, setting the branch pattern to "master" and the number of required approving reviews is set to 1. But unfortunately, when I try to push to origin/master, it goes through.
Is this not the feature I want or is something not set right?

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

The problem was that I was admin for this repo and unless I tick the box <s>"Include administrators"</s> "Do not allow bypassing the above settings" I am allowed to do direct pushes.

[image: screenshot of GitHub config]

Curiously I am not shown as administrator under the repo's settings->Collaborators & Teams but I can see this using the Organisation's account.

Comment: Was struggling too... Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up that it looks like the "Include administrators" setting has been removed in favor of "Do not allow bypassing the above settings"