# GitHub still allows me to push directly to protected branch

Tags: github

In GitHub, I have the following rule active on a branch called 'main':

- Require a pull request before merging

But it still allows me to push directly to the protected branch.

We only have 1 branch and the settings show that the rules are applied to 1 branch. I am not sure what other settings I would need to change.

Comment: maybe that comment will be useful for you  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58542669/9271903

Comment: Yes this fixed it for me, if you submit an answer I will accept it. I was not able to find that specific question when researching a solution.

Comment: Thanx man.
I Submit it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to protect branch with "Require pull request reviews before merging"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541814/how-to-protect-branch-with-require-pull-request-reviews-before-merging/58542669#58542669)